# How to stop other images to move while dragging of one image

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch, android-imageview, android-event

In my application i am able to overlap images one by another, when i drag one image from the group of images the left and right images are also moving on the screen.
How restrict this, below is my code

```
    int cards[] = {R.drawable.c1,R.drawable.c2,R.drawable.c3,R.drawable.c4,R.drawable.c5,R.drawable.c6,
                R.drawable.c7,R.drawable.c8,R.drawable.c9,R.drawable.c10,R.drawable.c11,R.drawable.c12,R.drawable.c13};
    ImageView[] Images = new ImageView[cards.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {           
                Images[i] = new ImageView(this);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                if (i != 0) {          

                     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,i-1);
                     params.leftMargin= 40;
                     Images[i].setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), cards[i]));
                     Images[i].setId(i);
                     Images[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
                    layout.addView(Images[i], params);
                } else {
                     Images[i].setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), cards[i]));
                     Images[i].setId(i);
                     Images[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
                    layout.addView(Images[i], params);
                }

            }

//Ontouch

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event){
        params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)p_v.getLayoutParams();
        switch (p_event.getAction()){       
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            status = START_DRAGGING;            
            imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(p_v.getDrawingCache());

            m_lastTouchX = p_event.getX();
            m_lastTouchY = p_event.getY();  

            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
                status=STOP_DRAGGING;           
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
                m_dx = p_event.getX() - m_lastTouchX;
                m_dy = p_event.getY() - m_lastTouchY;

                m_posX = m_prevX + m_dx;
                m_posY = m_prevY + m_dy;
                System.out.println("Dragging");
                    params.leftMargin = (int) m_posX;

                    params.topMargin=(int) m_posY;
                    p_v.bringToFront();
                    p_v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    imageView1.invalidate();
                    m_prevX = m_posX;
                    m_prevY = m_posY;

            }


            break;

        }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: becouse you applied ontouch listener on relative layout which is parent layout

Comment: i didn't get you, where i need to set the ontouchlistner?

Comment: Any Help? Any one faced this kind of problem?

Comment: You should not try to do stuff like that using Android's layout hierarchy. Use a Canvas.

Comment: can you please give an example for this...

Comment: Or please tell me how to remove the rule added in loop...When i tried like params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)p_v.getLayoutParams();
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,0);    it doesn't work

Comment: I would very strongly suggest using the Honeycomb drag apis: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html . They will do most of the work for you.

Comment: but it requires API 11, but this should work below API versions also..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small snippet to get you going. I added some images into `RelativeLayout`. The drawing is done in canvas for better performance of dragging. You just need to handle the layout params update `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event:

```
private ImageView[] Images;
private boolean mDragging = false;
private Rect mImageRect = new Rect();
int mX = 0;
int mY = 0;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private ImageView mImage;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mX = (int) ev.getX();
        mY = (int) ev.getY();

        for (ImageView image : Images) {
            image.getHitRect(mImageRect);

            if (mImageRect.contains(mX, mY)) {
                mDragging = true;

                mImage = image;
                mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable())
                        .getBitmap();

                mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                postInvalidate();
                break;
            }
        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mDragging) {
            mX = (int) ev.getX();
            mY = (int) ev.getY();

            postInvalidate();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mDragging) {
            mDragging = false;
            mBitmap = null;
            mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImage = null;
        }
        break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    if (mBitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that because your images overlap, all three images get the onTouch event and start dragging. You should add some logic that would determine which image is the one that should drag (for example the one that processes the event first) and then START_DRAGGING only that image. You already have a "global" value status. Beside it just add int imageNo and set it in the ACTION_DOWN case statement.

While on the subject: you should only process ACTION_DOWN if status != START_DRAGGING.